# Wiring STM32 bluepill to STLINK-V3 for SWD debugging

Tags: datasheet, wiring

I want to debug an STM32 blue pill using the SWD debug interface of an [STLINK-V3](https://www.tme.eu/Document/a39a12e1c5ff4f25fb642503bf3a785a/DM00526767.pdf). Bluepill's SWD pinout is as follows:

[image]

And the STLINK-V3 SWD pins are as follows:

[image]

Should I power the target STM32(in this case blue pill) by using T_VCC of the STLINK-V3? I cannot figure out whether T_VCC is 5V or 3.3V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ST-Link can't power the target, so T_VCC is nothing. It's not an output, but input.

It needs target VCC to communicate at the same voltage on SWD pins.

Comment: Oh I see but is there any workaround?  If I USB connect/power both the ST-LINK and bluepill from a PC's USB ports would wiring SWCLK and SWIO work to make SWD debug work?

Comment: Why there needs to be a workaround and for what? The ST-Link needs the exact same VCC from target to communicate with the target, so it does not damage the target by driving SWD pins when target is for example unpowered.

Comment: Im confused. I power SD-LINKV3 by USB and dont know what its Vcc value. The bluepill has SWD pins one is 3.3V. I cannot figure out the Vcc values of these two. Vcc of what unit? Should the 3.3V pin of bluepill be wired to T_VCC pin of the STLINK?

Comment: Yes, you must give your target MCU supply to ST-Link T_VCC. And you must power the MCU board somehow, like with USB, and also use USB to ST-Link.